# Using multiple CSS Units in one line

Tags: javascript, css, units-of-measurement

Is it possible to use multiple units in one line of CSS code?
For example:

```
width: 20% + 5px;
```

Im presuming not. If so, how do you do it in a language such as javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sirko pointed out, there is [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Unfortunately there is a catch with using that function: out of the major browsers [IE <9 and Opera does NOT support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

If all you want is to include a padding then you can achieve the same thing with the [`box-sizing` attribute set to `border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/box-sizing) that has far [better browser support](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing). For IE<8 there is also a [polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) available.

```
.span20 {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;

    width: 20%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fzn8/) demonstrating the above.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
width: -webkit-calc(20% + 5px);
width:    -moz-calc(20% + 5px);
width:         calc(20% + 5px);
```

[**Browser Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)